Select2 looses css property and display html dd on multiple reload
I'm having some intermitten issue displaying select2 dropdown. Select2 dropdown works fine most of the time but sometimes it loses its css properties and just displays regular html dropdown. I'm reinitilazing the dropdown twice and that's how the app was designed. I tried couple solution but none of them seems to be working. For ex. destroying the select2 and reinitializing it on every api call, Checking if select2 is initialize by checking class 'select2-hidden-accessible'.
Anyone has experience similar issue with select2 or any help will be appreciated.
